# Is a micrometer a type of caliper?

Tags: terminology, metrology, experimental-technology

Wikipedia says:

> A caliper is a device used to measure the distance between two opposite sides of an object.

Therefor under this definition doesn't a micrometer also count as a caliper?

Comment: You can find plenty of information on callipers and micrometers in [this publication](http://publications.npl.co.uk/npl_web/pdf/mgpg40.pdf) from the National Physical Laboratory, UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a result of numerous comments and some investigation I have rewritten my answer.

The Oxford English dictionary defines "caliper" as follows:

> 1 (calipers}   An instrument for measuring external or internal
>   dimensions, having two hinged legs resembling a pair of compasses and
>   in-turned or out-turned points.
>   1.1 A measuring instrument having one linear component sliding along another, with two parallel jaws and a vernier scale.

Merriam Webster's dictionary has a slightly different definition for "caliper" and this is similar to the definition mentioned by @Dmckee:

> Any of various measuring instruments having two usually adjustable
>   arms, legs, or jaws used especially to measure diameter or thickness
>   —usually used in plural a pair of calipers

"Micrometer screw" from the Oxford dictionary:

> A screw of fine pitch attached to optical and other instruments for
>   making fine adjustments of position.

Micrometer from Merriam Webster's dictionary:

> 1 An instrument used with a telescope or microscope for measuring
>   minute distances
>   2 A caliper for making precise measurements that has
>   a spindle moved by a finely threaded screw

The [Wikipedia article "Micrometer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micrometer#History_of_the_device_and_its_name) uses the term "micrometer-screw calipers" and notes that such devices were introduced to the mass market by the company Brown and Sharpe who were founded in Providence, Rhode Island.

The Oxford dictionary defines "micrometer" as follows:

> A gauge which measures small distances or thicknesses between its two
>   faces, one of which can be moved away from or towards the other by
>   turning a screw with a fine thread.

It would seem to me that the term "micrometer screw gauge" is commonly used in the UK and "micrometer screw calipers" is commonly used in the US and any difference being masked by the usage of the shortened version "micrometer".

"England and America are two countries separated by the same language"

Comment: Micrometers can  be made to measure inside diameters. http://www.hzguodao.com/uploadfile/EnProduct/2011822101331976.jpg

Comment: Two remarks: at the beginning and in the second last paragraph, it is better to use the more correct word _resolution_ instead of _precision_; common vernier callipers   have a resolution of 0.05 mm, and dial callipers can reach 0.02 mm. Modern digital capacitive callipers can have a resolution of 0.01 mm.

Comment: I have to disagree with this answer. The word "caliper" unmodified by "vernier" or "dial" or "digital" means any adjustable opening device used for measuring distance. Consider this [image from the wikipedia page showing calipers from the early modern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calipers#/media/File:OutsideCalipers.jpg), and devices such at these were know in the classical period as well. In the modern laboratory we use the word as a shorthand for the more complete "vernier caliper" or "digital caliper". A c-geometry micrometer is a "caliper".

Comment: @dmckee I have always associated the word vernier with the word calliper so that was the reason for my answer. I have added the adjective to my answer. I assume that a calliper has two legs and gauge s a measuring instrument?

Comment: [Vernier's technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernier_scale) for getting an extra significant digit (or better) from a linear scale, by aligning it with a second scale whose markings have slightly different spacing, applies to instruments other than linear sliding calipers.  At some point in the past I used a rotating table that had a Vernier scale for angular measurements.

Comment: @rob Spectrometers have such vernier scales. Mitutoyo make micrometer with a vernier scale to get to a resolution of 0.000 mm which is shown on page 2 of their leaflet https://www.mitutoyo.co.jp/eng/products/menu/QuickGuide_Micrometers.pdf

Comment: @rob The Vernier technique is used in many type of measurements, e.g., is also employed by Keysight in their frequency counters to improve the resolution. In this case the two scales are made with two oscillators with slightly different frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

A [micrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micrometer) is so named because it's for high-precision length measurements.
There are several geometries:

[image: micrometers]

The first of these is a type of caliper, since it grabs either side of the object you're interested in.  The others, however, are for measuring interior lengths or depths, and "caliper" feels like the wrong word for those.

Comment: As I commented on Farcher's answer, also here it is better to use the more correct word _resolution_ instead of _precision_.

Comment: I would say that the fine resolution on a micrometer makes high-precision measurements possible, and stand by my original wording, but I think your comment is clarifying and useful.